# How to extend World in the context of cucumber-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am building an API with Rails, using the rails-api gem. I want to use cucumber-rails and the gem 'Airborne' to test it.

Airborne comes with some nice helper methods for testing API responses, which I want to have access to in my step definitions. I have done this kind of thing before in Sinatra, which was relatively straightforward to configure in the /features/env.rb file.

It seems, however, that with rails-cucumber the creation of the 'World' happens behind the scenes somewhere and I don't know how to extend it to use the Airborne module after it's been created.

I have tried the following:

```
Airborne.configure do |config|
  config.rack_app = Rails.application
end

Cucumber::Rails::World.extend(Airborne)

When(/^I make a request for information about an event$/) do
  get "/events/1"
end

Then(/^I receive the information as a JSON$/) do
  expect_json {} 
end
```

I am still getting a NoMethodError on #expect_json, which is an Airborne method.

So my question is: how can I extend the instance of World in the context of cucumber-rails?

Answer (score 1):

Don't panic, the World has been saved. The solution is to wrap Airborne and whatever else in a module:

```
module MyHelpers
  include Airborne
  include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Then pass that:

```
World(MyHelpers)
```